# Sendmail error in server log

Tags: ssh, sendmail, apache2

I am having a problem sending contact forms through contact form 7, when looking at the server log I'm getting the following error:

`sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?`

I've already searched for an answer to this which suggested to run the following cmd

`chown root:mailtrap /usr/sbin/sendmail
chmod 2755 /usr/sbin/sendmail`

I am now getting the following error.

`cwd=/home/spiralst/public_html 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did that last "error" come from? It seems like part of it is missing.

Comment: I found the error in /usr/local/apache/logs.error_log and the whole line looks like this. 

`[Tue Apr 10 18:03:12.594526 2018] [:error] [pid 50205:tid 140268839855872] [client 5.81.255.239:53118] 2018-04-10 18:03:12 cwd=/home/spiralst/public_html 3 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i, referer: http://domain/contact`

Comment: Strange...what came before and after it, then?

Comment: Before that I am getting this error

`[Tue Apr 10 18:02:59.566774 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 50205:tid 140268713977600] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 66.249.76.53:47421] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)` 

and after comes the samething

`[Tue Apr 10 18:04:02.687094 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6729:tid 140268724467456] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 66.249.76.54:45639] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)`

Comment: Hi Michael, I was able to get the error back to being `sendmail: Not running with correct effective GID.  Is sendmail binary setgid mailtrap?` as it seemed more documented.

Comment: What is reported by `grep -i RunAsUser /etc/mail/submit.cf`?